# Is There Any Way To Implement Multiple class Id's in a single javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have listed 4 elements in div class main ul li.
I want to hide these element when a button is clicked. I tried it with below code but only first `<li>` element is working

```js
function toggle(id){
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if(e.style.display == 'none'){
    e.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.main ul {
  display: table;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}

.main ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="btn" onclick="toggle(li)">hide</button>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it works for the first? I don't see how it can

Comment: *"I want to hide these element when a button is clicked."* They're already hidden by your CSS. (And no, it doesn't work for the first one unless you have a `var li = "one"` in your code you haven't shown us.)

Comment: JQuery `$('div.main li').each(e => ...);` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You want to loop through li elements with id's and hide them on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery for hide and show purpose as below. Initially, you apply display none property to your li element through css. It will hide elements on page load.

```
<div class="main">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li></ul></div>

<button class="btn" onclick="toggle()">hide</button>

.main ul{
  display:table;
  padding:2px 20px 2px 20px;
}

.main ul li{
  display:none;
}

function toggle(id) {

var e = $('ul')
if($('ul').is(":visible"))
   {
     $('ul').hide();
   }
else
   {
      $('ul').show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla solution
[demo and code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k29z9p4omv)

`li` is an tag, not id. So you have to get elements by tag using e.g.

`var elements = document.getElementsByTagName()`

Now you can't use `elements` directly because it's an array of elements. So you have iterate every element in an array e.g. using `for` loop like I did. Then you assign current element to the var, in my case `element` and create if statement as you do did it before.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because you are passing in the ul in the function which doesn't make any sense, That's why it won't work.

I have modified your code to the easiest way possible

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

btn.onclick = function(){
  ul.classList.toggle('newClass');
}
```

```css
.newClass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="btn">hide</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: _toggle_ functionality is not requested, I think just "hiding" them will do

Comment: I know sir, But I feel like he is trying to make a collapsable navbar  , I could be wrong

Comment: Could be, since the desired result is not really clear yet, we can just "sit and wait".